# Asynchronous way to listen web service for data change

Tags: python

I am new to python. I want to read JSON data from URL and if there is any change in JSON data on server, I want to update in my JSON file which is on client. How can I do that through python?

Actually i am ploting graph on django using JSON data which is on another server. That JSON data is updated frequently. So here i want to update my charts based on updated json data. For that i has to listen to URL link for change. So how can i do that.....i know with select() system call i can but need some another way

Comment: too broad. all we know is you have a json file

Comment: You are not providing enough context to receive a well formulated answer. Why does this task need to be achieved through Python and/or asynchronously? Is the client a server which you have full access to?

Comment: @jamylak i have url link of one json file and i want to listen to that link continuously. My question is how i will know that json data is changed so i could send request to get that data.

Comment: @arturhoo i am ploting graph on django based on JSON data which is on another server. That JSON data is updated frequently. So here i want to update my charts based on updated json data. For that i has to listen to URL link. So how can i do that.....i know with select() system call i can but need some another way..

Comment: You mentioned you are using Django, so I'm guessing the plot is part of a webpage. How are you generating the plot?

Comment: @arturhoo i am drawing graphs using django-graphos module and and i am updating models data using fixtures.json...hope u got it..

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to "listen" for changes other than repeatedly requesting that URL to check if something has changed; i.e. classic "pull updates". To get actual live notifications of changes, that other server needs to offer a way to *push* such a notification to you. If it's just hosting the file and is not offering any active notifications of any sort, then repeatedly asking is the best you can do. Try not to kill the server when doing so.